# Can you display the difference between two dates in months even if there's more than 12 in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, diff

I'm trying to find the difference between two dates and display it in months.

```
$currentDate = date_create(date('Y-m-d'));
$expiryDate = date_create('2022-12-10');
$dateDiff = date_diff($currentDate, $expiryDate);
$formattedDateDiff = $dateDiff->format('%m');
```

When I `var_dump($formattedDateDiff)` it just returns 0. Changing the `$expiryDate` reveals that it seems to be giving the leftover months after the years, i.e. if the expiry date was `'2022-01-10'`, it would give 1, as there's 3 years *and 1 month* between now and then, whereas I want the full 37 months.

When I `var_dump($dateDiff)` to see what it is that I'm actually formatting, it returns the following:

```
object(DateInterval)#830 (16) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(3)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["f"]=>
  float(0)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(1096)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

So it's obviously expecting every relevant unit to be displayed, rather than just one. Is there a way to return the total number of months in the `$dateDiff` object, rather than just the leftover months? I could just divide the days by 30, but that seems like such a naff way around it, and wouldn't exactly be the most accurate what with differing lengths of months and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant' you just multiply the years in difference for 12?

```
return $dateDiff->m + ($datediff->y * 12);
```